# Create a Relative layout at 30 % from bottom

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I am having an `imageView`below which I need to create a `RelativeLayout 2` that should be 70% from top and 30% from bottom and RelativeLayout from 30% top(ie at postion 30% as per screen resolution) and 70% bottom. Any inputs on how this needs to be implemented.

```
<RelativeLayout 1>
<ImageView1>
<RelativeLayout 2>
<TextView 1>
<ImageView 2>
.
.
.
</RelativeLayout 2>
</RelativeLayout 1>
```

Comment: Have you tried to set margins?

Comment: nope, can you help me with any sample ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout
...
layout_height="fill_parent"
orientation="vertical"
weightSum="100">
  <LinearLayout
   layout_width="fill_parent"
   layout_height="0dp"
   layout_weight="70"
  >
  </LinearLayout>
  <RelativeLayout
   layout_width="fill_parent
   layout_height="0dp"
   layout_weight="30">
  </RelativeLayout
</LinearLayout>
```

It's just a draft but i hope you do understand.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in each layout to set a margin by dp to each other layout

```
android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
// can be marginBottom, etc
```

The sample below just does what you need programatically. I have used a fixed size of (140,398).

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(140, 398);
        layoutParams.setMargins(24, 0, 24, 0);
        layout.addView(layoutParams);
```

Comment: I would be adding several(7 ) elements, adding them programatically is trouble soome